# Modify my ListView scrollBar

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar

I have the default ListView ScrollBar and i want to change it to this view:

[image]

So i took the [ScrollViewer ControlTemplate Example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970847(VS.85).aspx)

```
<Style x:Key="LeftScrollViewer" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"/>

          <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
            Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
          <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
            Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
            ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And out it inside `<Window.Resources>`.
Now since i am new with WPF i want to ask you what should be my next step to achieve this look. 
i found [this tutorial](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1525/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx) and under section `Large ScrollBars` you can see the view that i want but i don't know where to put this code and how finally to connect the new look with my `ListView` so any help will appreciate

Comment: You will also need to "ScrollBar" template. You would want to style both ScrollBars accordingly

Comment: can i have a code example ?